# Disable serialization strategy in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, serialization

Trying to find some [property](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) to disable serialization strategy. `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy` has other options, but how to disable it completely?

```
@GetMapping(produces = arrayOf("application/json"))
@ResponseBody
Obj handle(){
   return new Obj();
}

class Obj{
   String xValue = "value";
}
```

Default strategy changes `xValue` to `xvalue`:

```
{
   "xvalue":"value"
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to disable? Serialization of `xValue` property? Or do you want to keep an original name of property?

Comment: @VladimirL. `xValue` is just an example.I have lots of similar objects. I want to disable such behaviour for the whole app.

Comment: Have you tried to implement your own PropertyNamingStrategy?

Comment: Looks like the Jackson does not have a strategy like KEEP_ORIGINAL or so https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html, but you can use annotations to indicate the name how it should be serialized `@JsonProperty` into JSON.

Comment: @VladimirL. `@JsonProperty` also doesn't work. Seems implementing `PropertyNamingStrategy` is the only way to do it.

Comment: @VitalyZ nope, but it seems this is the only one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to completely disable Jackson's naming strategy.  By default, if no strategy is used, it will leave field names as-is.

> In absence of a registered custom strategy, default Java property
>   naming strategy is used, which leaves field names as is, and removes
>   set/get/is prefix from methods (as well as lower-cases initial
>   sequence of capitalized characters).

FYI, [here are some details about implementing your own custom naming strategy](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/03/entry_448.html) from the author of Jackson himself.

**Source**: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can use

```
spring.jackson.mapper.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING=true
```

in `application.properties` file to use default name of you bean